# Basic Wordpress/Buddypress CSS

Tags: css

I am on the latest Wordpress(3.8)/Buddypress(1.8). A very basic high level CSS question: I am having trouble making the CSS on my theme pages match the CSS in the sidebars and widgets and would like clarification on why different widgets, sidebars, and pages seem to be reading different CSS files. Shouldn't my theme CSS apply to all?

Here is my example page: http://uberon.net/news/

It has one left sidebar with the same two widgets as examples (Recent Posts and Posts in Sidebar). The appearance is drastically different in the sidebar vs the main page. Any help on how to point all to one CSS file or clear this up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty typical behavior. There will frequently be CSS that specifically targets items in the sidebar but not in the main page content. So, an example on your site would be that the "Read more" links are gray in the sidebar but blue in the main area of the page. This is caused by a CSS selector that targets links that are contained in a sidebar widget:

```
    div#main .widgets-container.sidebar_location a:not(.button) {
        color: #666666;
    }
```